# X out of Y people recommend - microformat markup

Tags: microformats

I'm in the process of marking up a site with microformats, using hcard, hreview and hreview-aggregate.

The documentation on http://microformats.org/ and http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/topic.py?topic=21997 is pretty good.

However one thing has got me totally stumped - Can anybody explain to me how I can express something in the form:

X out of Y people recommend...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like hreview-aggregate to me. A simple recommendation doesn't necessarily have a numeric value, but you can arbitrarily assign one based on the number of people. The scale will keep changing, but the proportions will stay the same. Example:

```
<div class="hreview-aggregate">
  <span class="item">...</span>
  <span class="rating"><span class="average">90</span> out of <span class="best count">100</span> people recommend.</span>
</div>
```

So every time you add a new person, both best and count would change. That makes sense, since the best scenario would be everyone recommending. That may be a bit misleading, since people aren't really rating on a 100-point scale, but the average of 90% is still accurate.

Comment: Thanks Scott.
That makes perfect sense. In the meantime I've gone and have been trying out a slightly different solution, as I have another value that I can use as a rating:
`code`
<div class="hreview-aggregate">
   <span class="item">...</span>
   <span class="rating" title="This review scored an average of 5 out of 5">5</span>
<span class="count">

Comment: Sorry (newbie error)
`code` 
<div class="hreview-aggregate"> 
<span class="item">...</span> 
<span class="rating" title="This review scored an average of 5 out of 5">5</span> 
<span>Based on <span class="count">3</span> reviews</span>
<span class="summary">3 out 3 people recommend this item</span>
</div>
`code`